# What is an efficient way to rig a character made of 2 meshes?

Tags: game-engine, rigging

I've already tried rigging this character a few times with little success. A little background if the picture isn't completely clear: I have 2 meshes, one is the painted model, and the other is the outline around the character (a mesh with the normals reversed and a shadeless black material). I want both meshes to be rigged identically (or near identically) so the outlines isn't warped too much as the character moves. It sounds simple, but my previous attempts have been to no avail. Should I join the separate objects together and then rig them as one hardly cohesive unit? Or just wing it and rig each one individually with the same armature?

I'm sorry if my question seems like something I should figure out on my own. I'm just wondering if there is a solution outside of my experience level. Also, since outline a character the way I have done is becoming more popular, this question could definitely help you, or others in the future.

If you need for information on my character let me know. I would be willing to share the blend file, but I will exclude the painted textures. Thank you in advance for your time.

[[image: Picture related. The character I'm attempting to rig[1]]

Answer (score 2):

After you have created the rig have you tried parenting the same portion of the mesh on both objects to the same bones? This should correct any issues you are having with rigging. You could join then meshes together as well but it makes little difference on the end result.

Comment: Thank Nathan. Didn't see your answer right away. What you said is about how I solved it. I took an older already animated rig and then duplicated the mesh, flipped verts, and scaled different parts of the mesh in edit mode with proportional editing to my preference. All of the existing animations and poses seem to work flawlessly. So the key for outlining a character, seems to be to just do it after the character is done, haha.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on the vertex groups (weights) and the vertex positions.

Typically it should be enough to armature parent with automatic weights. Be aware when you adjust weights on vertices of one mesh you need to adjust accordingly at the other mesh.

To make that easier you might join the meshes into a single one. You can separate them later (if you really want).

Comment: Thanks for the response, Monster. I think I was able to solve this last night with a rig I already had, kind of unexpectedly.  I duplicated the mesh after everything else and then, flipped the vertices, changed material, and scaled it up in edit mode and it seems to have kept all of the weights accurately. I just tried it with a few existing animations in the game engine so far, but it seems to work well, and it's really simple to do. This might be the best way to go about this method.